# Java Unicode Problems (I think)

Tags: java, unicode, java.util.scanner

I'm new to Java, so bear with me if I say anything stupid! I'm having a few problems, which I think are Unicode-related.

I'm using `Scanner` to read in tokenised commands from a text file, saved with UTF-8 encoding. Basically I want to first check that the command isn't equal to either "command1" or "command2" (I do something else in these cases), then otherwise read in a character. If the token isn't a single character, I'm going to output an error.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String command = scanner.next();
        if (command.equals("command1")) {
            System.out.println("command: command1");
            // do something
        } else if (command.equals("command2")) {
            System.out.println("command: command2");
            // do something
        } else {
            if (command.length() == 1) {
                char c = command.charAt(0);
                System.out.println("character: " + c);
                // do something with c
            } else {
                System.err.println("error (string was " + command
                        + " with length " + command.length() + ")");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the contents of the text file whose filename I'm passing in args[0] for testing:

```
command1
x
y
command2
z
└
command1
╒
═
```

Expected output is:

```
command: command1
character: x
character: y
command: command2
character: z
character: └
command: command1
character: ╒
character:  ═
```

Actual output is:

```
command: command1
character: x
character: y
command: command2
character: z
error (string was └ with length 3)
command: command1
error (string was ╒ with length 3)
error (string was ═ with length 3)
```

As you can see, the non-standard characters are being seen as a 3-character string by Java. Strangely, if I copy/paste the one of the characters from the terminal output into a `System.out.println("└".length())` statement, it correctly prints `1`.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: "If the token isn't a single character, I'm going to output an error." Note that the `length()` method on `String` return the number of UTF-16 code units, not the number of characters. These are often but not always the same.

Comment: @bames53 Thanks for pointing that out. Is there a better way of testing for whether or not a String is a single character, or is this just a potential gotcha to watch out for?

Comment: it depends on what you mean by 'single character'. If a sensible definition for your use case is that a code point is a character, then you only have to watch out for surrogate pairs. If you need a definition that allows for things like combining characters then at the very least you'll probably want a library that knows all about Unicode properties and whatnot. -- Dealing with Unicode text is complicated. Honestly, a lot of software out there gets it wrong but still manages to be useful. So you might want to learn a bit about it, but may decide it's not worth the effort to implement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you open files in Java, the encoding (if you don't specify one) is taken from the `file.encoding` system property. This is almost never set to something that you want (if you're like me, you always want UTF-8).

To fix, explicitly specify your character set when you create your Scanner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem comes indeed from an encoding mismatch.
Have you tried passing a Charset in the Scanner's constructor ?

Your code works perfectly on my system (Arch Linux 64b, java 6.0.30), with a default locale in UTF-8. If you run Windows, your locale may be Win-CP1252, which could be used by the Scanner.