# Use Get-Content in powershell as java input get extra character

Tags: java, powershell

I am practicing to use command line to run java script in windows 10.The java script is using `scanner(System.in)` to get input from a file and print the string it get from the file.The powershell command is as follow:

```
Get-Content source.txt | java test.TestPrint
```

The content of  source.txt file is as follow:

```
:
a
2
!
```

And the TestPrint.java file is as follow:

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestPrint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(in.hasNextLine())
        {
            String str = in.nextLine();
            if(str.equals("q")) break;
            System.out.println( str );          
        }
    }

}
```

Then weird thing happed.The result is

```
?:
a
2
!
```

You see,It add question mark into the begging of first line.Then when I change the character in first line of the source.txt file from ":" to "a",the result is

```
 a
a
2
!
```

It add space into the begging of the first line.

I had tested the character and found the regularity：if the character is larger than `"?"` in ASCII,which is 63 in ASCII,then it will add space,such as `"A"`(65 in ASCII) or `"["`(91 in ASCII).If the character is smaller than "?", including "?" itself ,it will add question mark.

Comment: PS:*source.txt* is when I want to use bold,but it didn't work well.There is no syntax error.

Comment: What's your [`PS C:\> $OutputEncoding`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/outputencoding-to-the-rescue/)? Why did you choose the [`scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.InputStream)) constructor that uses the user's system's current  "default" encoding?

Comment: When you say, "*source.txt* is when I want to use bold" do you mean you were just trying to bold source.txt in the question but what you are really entering from the command line is: Get-Content source.txt | java test.TestPrint

Comment: @CharlieWallace Yeah,you are right.That is what I means.What a newbie I am!!I have found the way to edit my post .And it seems the code area cannot add bold formatting.

Comment: @TomBlodget Sorry,I cannot post the entire result of `$OutpurtEncoding` because  the comment seems cannot use code block.I think the related part in the result is: `EncodingName      : US-ASCII`    `WindowsCodePage   : 1252`

Comment: @TomBlodget By the way,if I change the charset of scanner constructor into `"US-ASCII"` The println will add three question mark into the begging of the first line.

Comment: ? and � indicate to our users that we have lost some of their text by decoding bytes that represent text with the wrong character encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no text but encoded text.

Every program reading a text file or stream must know and use the same character encoding that the writer used.

An adaptive default character encoding is a 90s solution to a 70s and 80s problem (approx).  Today, it's usually best to avoid constructors and methods that use a default, and in PowerShell, add an encoding argument where needed to control input or output.

To prevent data loss, you can use the Unicode character set throughout. UTF-8 is the most common for files and streams. (PowerShell and Java use UTF-16 for text datatypes.)

But you need to start from what you know the character encoding of the text file is. If you don't know this metadata, that's data loss right there.

Unicode provides that if a file or stream is known to be Unicode, it can start with metadata called a BOM. The BOM indicates which specific Unicode character encoding is being used and what the byte order is (for character encodings with code units longer than a byte). [This provision doesn't solve any problem that I've seen and causes problems of its own.]

(A character encoding, at the abstract level, is a map between codepoints and code units and is therefore independent of byte order. In practice, a character encoding takes the additional step of serializing/deserializing code units to/from byte sequences. So, sometimes using or not using a BOM is included in the encoding's name or description.  A BOM might also be referred to as a signature. Ergo, "UTF-8 with signature.")

As metadata, a BOM, if present, should used if needed and always discarded when putting text into text datatypes. Unfortunately, Java's standard libraries don't discard the BOM. You can use [popular libraries](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html) or a dozen or so lines of your own code to do this.

Again, start with the knowing the character encoding of the text file and inserting that metadata into the processing as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I think it may be something wrong with my eclipse installation,for I have tried the same java program and file in another computer,everything is fine.

Comment: That's the problem with writing code that depends on an adaptive default. Also you do have to know the encoding of the text file. If you are using Eclipse to create it, you either told it which encoding to use or it picked one for you. You should configure it for the one you want.

Comment: I have found the solution by changing windows 10 system's setting.Change the setting of the _language for non-unicode programs_,and _uncheck the box of beta_.

Comment: Sure, it works now, for you, on that computer.  (And the irony for Windows choice of wording is that both PowerShell and Java use Unicode natively. Unfortunately, in general, they both desperately cling to this old idea of dynamically adapting to user settings that users don't generally know or care about.)

Comment: Haha. You are right.Even after I solved the problem,I cannot be sure what the detail reason is.I know this do not help with the issue,but I still want to  thanks for your patient.It really  encourage me to continue my programming

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a Unicode issue (See: [Java Unicode problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085433/java-unicode-problems-i-think))? i.e. try specifying the type you want to read in:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
```

EDIT:

Upon further research, PowerShell 5.1 and earlier, the default code page is Windows-1252. PowerShell 6+ and cross platform versions have switched to UTF-8. So (from the comments) you may have to specify Windows-1252 encoding:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "Windows-1252");
```

To find out what encoding is being used, execute the following in PowerShell:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default
```

And you should be able to see what encoding is being used (for me in PowerShell v 5.1 it was Windows-1252, for PowerShell 6 it was UTF-8).

Comment: Yes,It seems to be Unicode issue.If I change the encoding to `"UTF-8"`,then it will add question mark to the begging of the first line no matter what character the first line is .So Does it mean I should change the the encoding to my system's default encoding as @Tom Blodget said?

Comment: Yes I would try what @TomBloget said, try "Windows-1252" as the encoding, or what your default encoding is.

Comment: @earwen I have edited the Answer to reflect that there may be alternate encoding, depending on the version of PowerShell, as well as how to find out your current encoding method.

Comment: Yeah,I have tried the `"Windows-1252"` as the encoding in scanner constructor.But it turn out  three question mark  was added at the beginning of the first line.I think there may be something wrong with my eclipse program setting.I am ready to reinstalled it because everything was fine in my another computer with the same java program and txt file.